# How to specify addition and subtraction in a function？

Tags: racket

I'm making a function that adds or subtracts x and y from the original coordinates.This function accepts a command ("left", "right", "up", "down") an (x, y) position, and a non-negative distance and produces a new point moving according to the command and distance.It's like "left" x-num, "right" x+num, "down" y+num, "up" y-num. For example, if you start at (2, 3), the command "left" 1 should produce (1, 3), whereas "down" 2.2 would produce (2, 5.2). Each part might works, but how can I add them into one function.

This is my code:

```
    (define POSN-0 (make-posn 5 5))
    (define POSN-1 (make-posn 10 10))
    (define POSN-2 (make-posn 20 20))
    
(define (shift-left p)
  (make-posn (- (posn-x p) num)
             (posn-y p)))
(define (shift-right p)
  (make-posn (+ (posn-x p) num)
             (posn-y p)))
(define (shift-up p)
  (make-posn (posn-x p)
             (- (posn-y p) num)))
(define (shift-down p)
  (make-posn (posn-x p)
             (+ (posn-y p) num)))
```

How can I add all this in one function? Also, how can I define the add/subtract number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your edit, it's a little bit more clear what do you want, so here is my try.

Anyway, when you work with specific language ([BSL](https://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/beginner.html) in this case), you should mention that in the question. This will lead to answers more useful to you.

And see also [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72297642/racket-begineer-student-language-function-confusion)- it seems that you're both attendees of the same course, so I suggest you to join forces and next time, post one well-thought question and not two similar.

```
(define (shift command p dist)
  (cond
    ((string=? command "left")
     (make-posn (- (posn-x p) dist)
                (posn-y p)))
    ((string=? command "right")
     (make-posn (+ (posn-x p) dist)
                (posn-y p)))
    ((string=? command "up")
     (make-posn (posn-x p)
                (- (posn-y p) dist)))
    ((string=? command "down")
     (make-posn (posn-x p)
                (+ (posn-y p) dist)))))
```

Examples:

```
> (define p0 (make-posn 2 3))

> (shift "left" p0 1)
(make-posn 1 3)

> (shift "down" p0 2.2)
(make-posn 2 5.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You most certainly can have multiple parameters to a given function, and indeed you can see this with such built-in functions as `+` and `-`, as well as in the constructor `(make-point)` (which takes the four parameters as currently defined).

Speaking of which, what are the `xp` and `yp` members of the `point` structure for? A point in 2-dimensional space only need two coordinates. What are the other two for? Also, the `(define-struct)` form is deprecated in favor of the `(struct)` form, but that's not really important here.

As for how you would implement the 'commands', assuming that you are referring to the `(command-point)` function, you would have a parameter for the operation, another for the distance to move, and a case analysis (e.g., a `(cond)` form, or series of `(if)` forms, or in this instance, a `(case)` form) switching on the given command. Something like the following (untested code, you'll probably need to make adjustments):

```
(define (command-point p cmd dist)
  (case cmd 
    (`left  (make-point (- (point-x1 p) 1) (point-y1 p) (point-xp p) (point-yp p)))
    (`right (make-point (+ (point-x1 p) 1) (point-y1 p) (point-xp p) (point-yp p)))
    (`fwd   (make-point (point-x1 p) (- (point-y1 p) 1) (point-xp p) (point-yp p)))
    (`back  (make-point (point-x1 p) (+ (point-y1 p) 1) (point-xp p) (point-yp p)))))
```

Note that this doesn't change the `point` passed through `p`; it instead generates a new `point` structure.

I hope this is what you were looking for, as to be honest your question wasn't entirely clear.

Comment: I was told that I should use posn in BSL like (posn-x ...) and (posn-y ...) to extract each component. "If I understand you correctly, adding the ability to move a point to the "left" requires you somehow figuring out what you need to add / subtract to the individual x and y values to move it to the left the same way you would on a normal graph. " That's what he said. I think I know how to do the add and subtract, but when you define a x or a y in a function, can you add another variable? Like f(x)= x-num